# WebStorm generates bad import paths

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, tsconfig

My project has this structure:

```
root/
---tsconfig.json
---app/
------main.ts
---lib/
------public_api.ts
------files/
---------index.ts
---------file2.ts
---------file3.ts
```

The `index.ts` file in `lib/` is a barrel file that exports all files in `./files`:

```
# index.ts
export * from './file2';
export * from './file3';
```

The `public_api.ts` file exports whatever the barrel exposes

```
# public_api.ts
export * from './files'
```

Finally, `tsconfig` has a path alias for all files under `lib/` like this:

```
    "paths": {
      "lib": ["lib/public_api.ts"]
    }
```

With this setup, from within my app's `main.ts` I can import my library classes without using the full path:

```
# main.ts
import { File2Class } from 'lib';
```

That works well, and my IDE (PhpStorm / Webstorm) will know to automatically generate imports with the path alias when I'm in `main.ts`.

The problem is that sometimes when I am within a `lib/files/*.ts` file and I use a class from a sibling file, the IDE will use the same alias, so from within `file3.ts` It would auto-generate one of these imports:

```
# file3.ts
import { File2Class } from 'lib';
or
import { File2Class } from './';
```

This causes a hard to debug compilation error though.  The correct import from a sibling file would be:

```
# file3.ts
import { File2Class } from './file2';
```

So my question is: is it possible to instruct Webstorm/PhpStorm to never use a parent path and to never import from the barrel in the current or parent directory?

Comment: please try playing with **Use path mapping from tsconfig.json** option in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript** (set it to **Only in files outside specified paths**) - does it make things any better?

Comment: Thanks @lena I will give that a try